# Error trying to encode PDF in Code by Zapier

Tags: encoding, base64, zapier

I'm trying to read a pdf and encode it via JS Code in Zapier. Does anyone know how can I encode a Google Drive PDF file?

Trying to do this:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
let buff = fs.readFileSync('https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf');
let base64data = buff.toString('base64');
output = [{fileEncoded: base64data}];
```

But receivingthis error:

```js
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf'
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Node's `fs` module deals with the **f**ile**s**ystem, so you can't use it to download files from the web.

Try adapting this example from [this github issue](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/issues/375#issuecomment-385751664):

```js
async function download() {
  const res = await fetch('https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/modules/logos_page/Octocat.png');
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream('./octocat.png');
    res.body.pipe(fileStream);
    res.body.on("error", (err) => {
      reject(err);
    });
    fileStream.on("finish", function() {
      resolve();
    });
  });
}
```

You can use `await` in Zapier JS without any extra work